# Customize and correct, menu options

Tags: angularjs

The options menu is working correctly, looking for firebase values,
I would like to customize the checkbox with css but I can't do it,
Another mistake is that the first option is empty,
any way to make this menu more attractive?

I'm using angularjs to capture firebase data

[image]
[image]

**controller**

```
function getDados() {
  $http.get('https://auto-deliv.firebaseio.com/produtos.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.dados = data;

  });
}
```

**Html**

```
<label for="cars">Escolha a categoria:</label><select ng-model="results">
<option ng-repeat="x in dados.categorias" >{{x.categoria}}</option>
</select>

<div id="conteudo">

<div id="filtro">
    <img id="icon-lupa" src="images/iconLupa.png" />
    <input id="buscar-local" type="text" name="local" ng-model="searchFood" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
</div>

<div id="pedidosRapidos">
    <ul id="lista-pratos">
        <li ng-repeat="prato in dados.food | filter: searchFood | filter: results" ng-click="pedidoRealizado(prato.title, prato.price, prato.pricem, prato.pricep)">

            <div class="descricao">

                <img ng-src="{{prato.imageUrl}}" alt="" />
                <h3>{{prato.title}}</h3>
                <p>{{prato.desc}}</p>
                <h4>{{prato.price | currency}}</h4>
                <button>adicionar</button>
                <br>

            </div>

        </li>

        <h2 ng-show="results.length < 1">{{results.length}} Resultados</h2>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to improve your question and justification, so it improves more readability. Please improve your question context. Your justification is not enough to understand the question.

Comment: Take a look at the images, maybe you can understand me

Comment: @WellingtonVieira Would be very helpful to resolve your query if you can share the working jsfiddle/demo code.

Comment: Add image & reformat code